# How to make a custom function that returns cell contents?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use this function to reference a cell.  if the cell has anything in it then return the contents.  If the cell is blank, then return "-".  Here is the code I am using and receiving an "invalid use of property" error.  here is the code:

```
Function rd(rng As Range)    
Dim blank As String

blank = "-"
If rng.Value > 0 Then
    rng.Value
Else
    blank
End If

End Function
```

Comment: why not just an IF test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Function rd(rng As Range)

Dim blank As String

blank = "-"

If rng.Value > 0 Then
        rd = rng.Value
    Else
        rd = blank
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing this out of interest rather than efficiency, so something like this as

- range could be more than once cell
- your formula would return "-" for any text entries

  ```
  Function rd(rng As Range) As String

  Dim blank As String
  blank = "-"

  If Len(rng.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
         rd = rng.Cells(1).Value
     Else
         rd = blank
  End If

  End Function
  ```